# How to use push pull in bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to use a push, pull in Bootstrap [v5.0.0-beta2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), but how?

In Bootstrap 3, I'm using it like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

I tried. But I can't. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saptamdev/12y6kpgr/)

In Bootstrap V5, how can I use push and pull?
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Push/pull is a grid technique.  That's now deprecated in favour of flex.
For flex the helper classes are `.order-`.  See BS5 [Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#reordering) documentation.

You can use global ordering:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      First in DOM, no order applied
    </div>
    <div class="col order-5">
      Second in DOM, with a larger order
    </div>
    <div class="col order-1">
      Third in DOM, with an order of 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or screen size specific ... i.e. `.order-sm-*`, `.order-lg-*`, and so on.

If you just want to shift, then use [Offsetting Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#offsetting-columns)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

In your case you can use:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 order-last">.col-md-9 <del>.col-md-push-3</del><ins>order-last</ins></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 order-first">.col-md-3 <del>.col-md-pull-9</del><ins>order-first</ins></div>
</div>
```

or:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 order-2">.col-md-9 <del>.col-md-push-3</del><ins>order-2</ins></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 order-1">.col-md-3 <del>.col-md-pull-9</del><ins>order-1</ins></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want to do something as I asked. 
I want it for responsive. https://jsfiddle.net/saptamdev/12y6kpgr
If I want to shift the 2nd column first. Then how to do it?

Comment: I'll edit the answer to add a specific example to your code.